# Is the Buffalo River at King Williams Town navigable by boat?

Tags: south-africa, riverboats

According to https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Buffalo_River_(Eastern_Cape) the Buffalo River is the only navigable river in South Africa, and boating on the river is certainly possible at the port city of East London.

King William’s Town is about sixty kilometers upriver.

Is boating on the river possible as far upriver as King William’s Town?

Comment: What do you mean by "navigable"?  From looking at google there are 2 obvious dams downstream of King William's town. There appears to be water upstream of each of  them, but you aren't going to be cruising from the coast all the way to the town

Comment: [Offhand I'm going to say no.](https://goo.gl/maps/Wy7CRZr5geAAvE189)

Comment: There also appear to be [major rocks in the river in East London itself,](https://goo.gl/maps/tf2fDuV2EuAdbe927) a mere 7 km from the coast.  Of course, water levels may vary by season.

Comment: People also raze each year on the Umzumduzi from Pietermaritzburg to Durban, so not the only one...